# Sum of span values in For loop (working in IE10)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum, internet-explorer-10

I have the following values within span tags:

```
<div id="aantallen">
 <span>3</span>
 <span>2</span>
</div>
```

In JS I want to get the sum of these values. I have this code to do it (which works, ... but):

```
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('#aantallen span');

const result = Array.from(spans).reduce((sum, spanElm) => sum + Number(spanElm.textContent), 0)
```

However, this code is not working in Internet Explorer 10 (and probably older versions) because ECMA 6 arrow is not supported.

Now I'm trying to code something that will also work in IE but I don't quite get it yet. I do have a version where I can use the texts in the spans but I can't get it to convert to integers because I get NaN errors:

```
var div = document.getElementById("aantallen");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
console.log(spans);
var totaalPersonen = 0;
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
    alert(parseInt(spans[i]));
    totaalPersonen = parseInt(totaalPersonen) +parseInt(spans[i]);
    //alert(totaalPersonen);
}
alert(totaalPersonen);
```

How can I convert the span values to integers and make a sum of them?

Comment: You're better off using a transpiler and just writing modern code. Reduce still works in IE10, just convert the HTMLCollection to an Array with splice if you have to

Comment: `spans` is a collection of elements, so `parseInt(spans[i])` gives `NaN` because a DOM element aint no number! `spans[i].textContent` might work. You can use `reduce` too, just dont use an arrow function: `Array.from(spans).reduce(function(sum, spanElm) { return sum + Number(spanElm.textContent), 0) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing spans directly and trying to add them up; instead you have to access the content within the span.

Check the following snippet:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("aantallen");
var spans = div.querySelectorAll("span");

var totaalPersonen = 0;
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
   const content = Number(spans[i].innerHTML)
    alert(content);
    totaalPersonen = Number(totaalPersonen) +content;
    alert(totaalPersonen);
}
```

```html
<div id="aantallen">
 <span>3</span>
 <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the insight! The code works and i see where my error was. For some reason, the 3 and 2 are correctly shown in the alert, but when the sum should be shown, it still says NaN. It definitly an error on my side so I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the object correctly but not accessing it's value properly, you need to use innerHTML in each element to get it.

You are using: (it's the DOM node object)

```
spans[i]
```

You need to use: (the respective DOM node **innerHTML** value)

```
spans[i].innerHTML
```

I have built a functional jsfiddle, take a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpichioli/w3m0cc1g/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, but thanks for this tip! Happy new year!